# The API v0.9 2010.06.24.002 as seen by SOAPI

Tags: discussion, api

### Stack Overflow API as seen by the SOAPI parser and code generator:

With the API freeze, changes to the vast API should slow to a trickle, making manual maintenance possible. At this milestone, I have suspended code generation and manually refactored the entire SOAPI library.

In doing so I have reduced the redundancies that are the inevitable result of code generation so the model is much cleaner and presents an accurate view of the API.

One area which I will refrain from refactoring further until v1.0 are the parameters. It should be obvious that the parameter types would benefit from abstraction into interfaces and base classes but until this critical area is truly frozen I will continue to use discreet parameter types for each route.

StackAuth methods are now folded into SOAPI.

**NOTE**: Some browsers will not give you a full resolution view on images this size. FF and IE seem to behave, Chome is choking a bit and won't zoom to full resolution. If you have trouble viewing the images clearly try another browser or save them to disk.

### Routes

[image: Routes]

**[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCqQZ.png)**

---

### Parameters

[image: Parameters]

**[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vRGY.png)**

---

### Responses

[screenshot removed ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising/264155#264155))]

Comment: @system - glad you liked it.

Comment: There are a few places where some more normalization could be implemented with some specific code generation rules but until the API stops moving so fast I don't see the point in wasting time.

Comment: You get an upvote for including pretty charts.

Comment: Believe it or not, *Opera Mini* has no problem displaying the images.

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be a very useful view of the data. Thanks for doing this. One suggestion would be to include the types for each property. This would make it easy at a glance to see more of what each thing represents.

Comment: ask and ye shall receive.